# Multiple entity one to many joins

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity that I need to link to it multiple sub entities, my example is:
I have Invoice Header entity and I want to link to it using `@OneToMany` multiple entities, Invoice Adjustment and Prior Notice Entity .

So invoice header can have one or many Invoice Adjustment and one or many Prior Notice.

I'm fine to link to one entity but not sure how can I link to the other one as I'm trying different options and not working,

for example below is my code and error.

```
public class InvoiceHeader extends InvoiceProcessing{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Size(max = 1)
private String recordId;
@Size(max = 1)
private String action;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceHeader", cascade = 
  CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<InvoiceAdjustment> invoiceAdjustments = new ArrayList<>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "priorNotice", cascade = 
  CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<PriorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmin> priorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmins = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class InvoiceAdjustment extends InvoiceProcessing{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String recordId;
private String reserved;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "invoiceHeader_id")
  private InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader;
}


public class PriorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmin extends InvoiceProcessing{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String recordId;
private String reserved;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "priorNotice_id")
   private InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader;
}
```

here is the error I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.invoiceconverter.invoiceconverter.model.PriorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmin.priorNotice in com.invoiceconverter.invoiceconverter.model.InvoiceHeader.priorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class InvoiceHeader extends InvoiceProcessing{
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceHeader", ... )
    private List<InvoiceAdjustment> invoiceAdjustments = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceHeader", ...)
    private List<PriorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmin> priorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmins = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

`mappedBy` names the attribute on the associated entity which defines the foreign-key for this association.  Which in both cases is an attribute named "invoiceHeader".

Also, you probably did not mean "priorNotice_id" for the FK column for `PriorNoticeFoodAndDrugAdmin#invoiceHeader` - I would think you'd name that column "invoiceHeader_id" as well